# SQL condition date

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

From this database, I want to select those data which `payment_date` is current month but the `service_date` is any month except this month.

[Database sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYtO6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to check if 2 dates are in the same month is with the use of the function [`last_day()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day), because if for 2 dates the last day of their month  is the same then they are in the same month:

```
select * 
from tablename
where last_day(payment_date) = last_day(curdate())
  and last_day(service_date) <> last_day(curdate())
```

If you want the results for any month and not for the current month only:

```
select * 
from tablename
where last_day(payment_date) <> last_day(service_date)
```

Comment: It returns empty.

Comment: Do you have payment_dates of the current month?

Comment: If you want results for any month and not just for the current month then check my 2nd query.

Comment: Yes, i have. @forpas

Comment: I don't see in your sample data any rows for this month. Post sample data that have payment_dates of the current month and service_dates that are not i the current month in text format.

Comment: I have updated image and now it's working with first SQL. It was actually my fault. There was no data with this month payment_date and any month service_date except this month.